# Is there any denomination that fully embraces Dispensational Premillennialism?

Tags: eschatology, denomination-survey, premillennialism, dispensationalism

I'm not a fan of dispensational premillennialism, but I don't know of any denominations that specifically hold to it. I'm just fairly curious. I've met individual people that believe it, but never an entire denomination that supports it. Do any such denominations exist?

Comment: the Plymouth Brethren do

Answer (score 8):

Dispensationalism tends to be most prevalent in baptist, charismatic, and non-denominational churches.  However, the largest baptist and charismatic denominations (like the Southern Baptist Convention and the Assemblies of God) do not take a firm stance on a pre-tribulation, pre-millennial rapture.  Still, there are sizable denominations and associations of churches that specifically hold to this doctrine.

A full list is beyond the scope of this site, but one major charismatic denomination holding to this is the [International Pentecostal Holiness Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Pentecostal_Holiness_Church) (3.5 million members).  Its statement of faith reads:

> The second coming of Christ will occur in two stages; the first for the purpose of catching away His saints who are prepared for the Rapture before the Great Tribulation period; and the second at the end of the Great Tribulation, when He shall come back with His saints to destroy the armies of the Antichrist, to judge the nations of the world, and to inaugurate the millennial reign. ([source](http://iphc.org/beliefs/))

Another group, perhaps not meeting your definition of "denomination," is [Calvary Chapel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvary_Chapel), an association of churches with about 25 million members in total.  It, too, clearly describes dispensational eschatology in its statement of faith:

> We believe in the Pre-Tribulation Rapture of the Church through which all believers will be caught up to meet the Lord in the air, and be taken out of the world prior to the Tribulation that will then come upon the earth. ([source](http://calvarychapel.com/about/doctrine/view/doctrine/))

So yes, not all denominations influenced by dispensationalism avoid clearly stating dispensational doctrine in their statements of faith: there are significant denominations and associations that specifically hold to the doctrine of a pre-tribulation, pre-millennial rapture.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to most Baptist groups, many non-denominational associations of churches, and the church groups of the more recent charismatic movements since the early 1960s which hold the doctrine, the two largest and most prominent Pentecostal denominations in both Canada and the USA also hold to the doctrine. In their statement of beliefs, under the heading "The End Of Time" and the sub-heading "The Rapture," the Pentecostal Assemblies Of Canada hold that:

> The rapture, the blessed hope of the church, is the imminent coming of the Lord in the air to receive to Himself His own, both the living who shall be transformed, and the dead in Christ who shall be resurrected. This event takes place before the wrath of God is poured out during the tribulation.

Clearly held above are the doctrines of Dispensational/Pre-Tribulational Premillennialism. And in the U.S., the Assemblies Of God word it this way in their belief statement:

> The 'imminent and blessed hope' of the Church is its rapture preceding the bodily return of Christ to earth. The rapture of the Church will be followed by the visible return of Christ and his reign on earth for a thousand years.

The belief of imminency in this latter statement necessarily requires an espousal of Pre-Trib Premillennialism as well.

However, the fairly large Vineyard Fellowship network, both in the USA and in Canada, one of the more recent charismatic groups to appear, has left it vague in its beliefs statement as to which variety of premillennialism it holds to, if any at all, though it certainly expresses a premillennial view.

Comment: Welcome, and nice answer! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](https://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a denomination proper, Bible churches also tend to stick to premillenial dispensationalism.  I am a member of one, and we hold to it, mostly.  However, I do not know what you mean by fully embracing it.  Dispensationalism has at least a couple of forms.  A more strict dispensational form has a corollary that says we are in a dispensation which is different than the one given to the apostles and very early church, so some of the gifts of the Spirit are no longer in play in our dispensation.

However, it seems that dispensationalism has shifted more and more to a recognition that there is nothing in the New Testament to indicate that those gifts are no longer applicable.  While I would consider myself a premillenial dispensationalist, I would say, with many others in the same camp, that all gifts of the Spirit are still possible, within the confines of how Scripture dictates their their purpose and manner of use.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer. Does your church have any affiliation, even if loose, with others that hold similar views? And can you provide links to doctrinal statements from your church relating to the question? If so, that would greatly strengthen your answer here. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Look up Dr Andy Woods from Sugar Land Bible Church [www.slbc.org](http://www.slbc.org) also Dr. Arnold Fruchtenbaum of Ariel Ministries. Be warned if you really desire to mature in Christ these people really have been raised by God in these last days to further reveal biblical truths that have been concealed until these times. Remember in scripture certain truths are further illuminated by the Sprit as we draw closer to the day of the Lord. Hope this helps and God Bless

Comment: That looks like a single church, not a denomination. Is it part of a denomination, and do they fully embrace dispensationalism?